# React/Redux performance difference between passing props and connecting components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a doubt regarding React/Redux, is there any difference performance-wise between a connected parent that passes props to all the children or  children components connected directly to the store?

As an example let's consider this pseudo-code with `SampleList` with `SampleItems`:

## Approach 1

```
<ConnectedSampleList>
  <SampleItem />
  <SampleItem />
  ...
  <SampleItem />
</ConnectedSampleList>
```

## Approach 2

```
<SampleList>
  <ConnectedSampleItem />
  <ConnectedSampleItem />
  ...
  <ConnectedSampleItem />
</ConnectedSampleList>
```

I am aware that the first approach looks like a better practice for a basic scenario, but what about more complex hierarchies, e.g. `ConnectedFooComponent` > `Wrapper` > `AnotherWrapper` > `SampleList` > `SampleItem` with `Wrapper`, `AnotherWrapper` and `SampleList` being shared with `FooComponent`, `BarComponent`, etc.

In this case passing props all the way down to `SampleItem` doesn't look clean anymore, and connecting each `SampleItem` sounds like a better idea, but how would it affect performance if the list contains millions of items?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Use Connect or pass data as props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300361/use-connect-or-pass-data-as-props-to-children/47300486#47300486)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that topic does not mention anything about performance of both approaches which is my main question

Comment: `Both approaches of passing props down to children or connecting them to the store are appropriate, however having nested connect() components is actually going to give you more performance.`

Comment: Ok, then it answers my question indeed, thanks @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :-)

Comment: https://reactrocket.com/post/react-redux-optimization/   good short and simple article which answers your question

Comment: Interesting article @Max, thanks!