# why is mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps defined in every file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

is there a reason people always seem to define these functions at the bottom of every component they are needed?

when ever I create a react/redux project I put these in a `/mappingFunctions` directory and then import them into the files I need them, thus declaring the functions just once. obviously means the functions include more than necessary but it means they are in just one place rather than defining them a million times.

just wondering why this is not the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component/container may need to access different set of variables from redux store and different set of actions. So mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are defined individually for all those components that need to interact with Redux store.

Also you don't need to use mapStateToProps, maDispatchToProps for each component. You can have a balance between passing props down or connecting each component to Redux store.

Check [Use Connect or pass data as props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300361/use-connect-or-pass-data-as-props-to-children/47300486#47300486) for more details

Comment: yeh I get that but I mean for each connected component, might as well just have a single source of truth and call the function in from a remote place. that way you have access to it, rather than redefining it everywhere. maybe what im saying doesn't make sense. just nice to define it one place rather than like 5000 times

Comment: @donut, its a matter to preference to define it a single place or in individual file. Personally I find it more readable if its in the same file. Also some people separate containers from components, where you just import and export the connected component.However you won't connect 5000 different components to store.

Answer (score 0):

Because the state and the actions passed to components are generally different

Answer (score 0):

- `mapStateToProps` - this is callback called by Redux when some part of the state is updated. It is used to update map Redux store changes to properties of your component. Each of your components is most probably interested in different parts of Redux store state. Your container components doesn't need to implement this if they don't need to be updated based on Redux store state updates.
- `maDispatchToProps` - this is callback used to create action closures connected to redux via dispatch. This way Redux store is aware of actions triggered by your component and can update its state accordingly. Your container component will use only handful of actions. It can happen that container component doesn't need to connect any actions, so you would not need to implement this.

If you find yourself duplicating same `mapStateToProps`/`maDispatchToProps` across various container components, you should probably reuse same container component on various places of your app and remove such code duplication this way.