# Is it considered a bad practice to nest container component inside a presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's suppose we have a table of data that is controlled by `Redux`. This table has some filters and buttons inside that also depend on the `Redux` state.

What would be the correct approach?
1) To create a container over the table, grab all the necessary data with `connect` and then pass it down to the table and then further to filters and buttons through props(with this approach the container components becomes cumbersome due to all the state variables and dispatches)
2) Create separate containers for all the elements inside the table that depend on Redux and then nest those containers inside the Table presentational component(this approach just doesn't feel right because of the "smart" components we have inside of the "dumb" component.

I've read some articles online, including the one written by Dan Abramov where he said that it's okay to nest containers inside components but almost all the articles I found seem to be 3-5 years old at this point. So I wanted to know what people deem to be the "right" at this moment in time

Comment: The concept has not changed, only the apis have. You can check this post : [Use Connect or pass data as props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300361/use-connect-or-pass-data-as-props-to-children/47300486#47300486)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for